# Prove that both iterated integrals exists but $f$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that the function $f$, given by:

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1  \iff (x,y) =(\frac p {2^n},\frac q {2^n}): (p,q,n) \in \Bbb N^3, 0<p,q<2^n \\0 \iff (x,y) \neq (\frac p {2^n},\frac q {2^n}) \end{cases}$$

Is such that

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy=0$$

But $f$ is not integrable in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$

I'm not really sure how to prove this, so any help will be great.

I was thinking that maybe one could prove that

$$\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx=0$$

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: For future note, use \times in place of x when you want to do $\times$ in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The set of points, where $f(x,y)=1$ is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but not (relatively) dense in $[0,1]$'s on the axes.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe one could prove that


$$\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx=0$$

Any thoughts on that?