# Iterated integral exists but $f$ is not integrable - clarification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1  \iff (x,y) =\left(\frac p {2^n},\frac q {2^n}\right): (p,q,n) \in \Bbb N^3, 0<p,q<2^n \\0 \iff (x,y) \neq \left(\frac p {2^n},\frac q {2^n}\right) \end{cases}
$$
I need to prove that the iterated integral on the rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is zero, i.e

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy=0$$

The question was asked before, but only a hint is given (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035785)

What does it mean "not (relatively) dense" in $[0,1]$? 

I am considering the function

$$F(x) = \int_{0}^1f(x,y)dy$$

which is evidently $0$ if  $x \ne \frac{p}{2^n}$ and I am trying to show is $0$ everywhere. 

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You don't have to show that F(x) is 0 for every x. It is 0 for almost all x (since countable sets have measure 0) and hence the integral of F is 0.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not familiar with measure theory, but I sort of understand that countable sets have measure 0. Is it possible to construct a partition of $[0,1]$ and show that the integral of $F$ is $0$? Or that is a painful way